# WinForms control docking in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxWidgets since I never use GUI when programming in C++. Now I have to. I want to make the UI responsive using something like the `DockStyle.Right/Bottom/Fill` from WinForms. Since I have no code I tried before, the question is very short and not the best but I hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:**
That is what I currently have. When I uncomment SetMaxSize there is 30px space at the bottom but the panel (blue) is not visible:

```
namespace tms {
    MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) {
        this->InitialiseComponents();
    }
    
    void MainFrame::InitialiseComponents() {
        this->panelChatLog = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
        this->panelChatLog->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0, 255, 0));
        
        this->panelChatInput = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
        this->panelChatInput->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0, 0, 255));
        this->panelChatInput->SetMinSize(wxSize(0, 30));
        //this->panelChatInput->SetMaxSize(wxSize(0, 30));

        this->sizerPanels = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        this->sizerPanels->Add(this->panelChatLog, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
        this->sizerPanels->Add(this->panelChatInput, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
        this->SetSizer(this->sizerPanels);
    }

    void MainFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event) {
        this->Close(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: wxWidgets has the wxAUI family of controls.  You can see a demo in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ua-iIpdZuI).  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @NewPagodi No too advanced. Not that type of docking. Just having a parent and you dock a child, e.g. a panel, to the right, so its placed on the right side always matching the parent's height but keeping its width. another child set to dock.fill would fill the remaining space. I googled a bit and I think it can be done using a horizontal wxBoxSizer, but I cannot make it work...

Comment: I see now.  I think you are correct - what you are trying to do is done in wxWidgets with sizers.  Sizers are a little tricky to learn at first. You might find a tools like wxFormbuilder or wxCrafter helpful to get started.  They help you see what all the sizer options do in real time.

Comment: @Matze, or you can install wxGlade which is not associated with any "wx" IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Learning sizers can be a little tricky at first.  But once you've absorbed the concept, they can be a very effective tool for laying out windows and controls for your application.

In the specific case above, when you uncomment the SetMaxSize line, you're setting both the min width and max width of the window to be 0 - which means the window has a width of 0.  Instead you can use the special value of -1 which means the min width is and max width are unspecified.  Consequently the sizer will pick the best width for the window:

```cpp
        this->panelChatInput->SetMinSize(wxSize(-1, 30));
        this->panelChatInput->SetMaxSize(wxSize(-1, 30));
```

Alternately, you can use the proportion property when adding the lower panel to sizer.  If you set the proportion to 0, the window will take it's minimum size (in the vertical direction).  It will still expand in the horizontal direction because of the wxEXPAND flag is set.

```
...
        this->panelChatInput->SetMinSize(wxSize(-1, 30));

        this->sizerPanels = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        this->sizerPanels->Add(this->panelChatLog, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
        this->sizerPanels->Add(this->panelChatInput, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL);
...
```

Either way, you'll get a layout that looks like this:
[image]

I think that's what you're trying to accomplish.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding.

Also as I mentioned above, visual tools like wxFormbuilder, wxCrafter, and wxGlade can be of help to see how all these numbers and properties translate to the actual layout of the windows in your application's forms. I know they really helped me.